# MobX not updating state

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I have two pages:

1. Page1 which shows a list of Records, each Record showing a counter
2. Page2 which lets you update the Counter

When tapping on an item in the list on Page1, you are taken to Page2 where you can update the counter value. Simple.

But I can't for the life of me figure out why the counter value in the list on Page1 isn't updating when updating the value on Page2.

Below is my code. I've left out irrelevant lines like styles, etc.

Here is my `Store`:

```
class RecordStore {
  data: any[] = [];

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  // Get the list data from backend
  getRecordData = async() => {
      try {
        const response = await postRequest('record/get');
        const json = response.data;
        const records = json.records;

        this.setData(records);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Set the data
  setData = (data: any) => {
    this.data = data;
  };

  // Used to update a single record in the data, matching the IDs
  updateRecord = (record: any) => {
    const result = this.data.map((item) => item.id === record.id ? record : item);
  }
}

// Instantiate the counter store.
const counterStore = new RecordStore();

// Create a React Context with the counter store instance.
export const CounterStoreContext = React.createContext(counterStore);
export const useRecordStore = () => React.useContext(CounterStoreContext)
```

Here is `Page1`:

```
const TabTwoScreen = observer(() => {
  const { data, getRecordData } = useRecordStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Get the record data to populate the list
    getRecordData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            return (
              <Observer>
                {() => 
                  <Link
                    href={{
                      pathname: "/record",
                      params: { recordId: item.id }
                    }} asChild>
                    <Pressable>
                      <View>
                        <Text>{item.counter}</Text>
                      </View>
                    </Pressable>
                  </Link>
                }
              </Observer>
            )
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
});

export default TabTwoScreen;
```

And here is `Page2`:

```
const Record = observer(() => {
  const { updateRecord } = useRecordStore();

  // Submit the updated record to the API
  // API returns the record's json
  const onSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await postRequest('record/update', { recordId: record?.id, counter: counter });
      const json = response.data;
      const jsonRecord = JSON.stringify(json.data);

      // Update the Store record
      updateRecord(jsonRecord);
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    // Simply shows a text field and a submit button
  );
});

export default Record;
```

What am I doing wrong that's causing the List item to not show the updated count when I go back from Page2 to Page1?

Thanks